# PySpark data-frame parallel process of partitions

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, foreach, apache-spark-sql

I want to process all partitions parallel. And, I've a data-frame as below:

```
df.show()
print("Before reparttion df.rdd.getNumPartitions():", df.rdd.getNumPartitions())
df = df.repartition('COL1')
print("After repartition df.rdd.getNumPartitions():", df.rdd.getNumPartitions())
```

Output:

```
+-----+
| COL1|
+-----+
|Hello|
|Hello|
|Hello|
|World|
|World|
+-----+

Before reparttion df.rdd.getNumPartitions(): 1
After repartition df.rdd.getNumPartitions(): 200
```

I know repartition creates 200 partitions by-default. So, here I'll have 198 partitions having 0 rows.

Now, I'm going to apply ForeachPartition on the DF.
I can use MapPartition as well, but I don't need data in return.
So, this is what I'm doing:

```
def my_func(row):
    print("my_func partition start-time: " + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + " : " + row['COL1'])
    time.sleep(10)

def process_partition(partition_rdd):
    data = list(partition_rdd)
    if len(data) > 0:
        for row in data:
            my_func(row)

df.rdd.foreachPartition(process_partition)
```

Output:

```
my_func partition start-time: 2022-01-12 02:40:33.617131 : World
my_func partition start-time: 2022-01-12 02:40:43.617869 : World
my_func partition start-time: 2022-01-12 02:40:53.637929 : Hello
my_func partition start-time: 2022-01-12 02:41:03.638729 : Hello
my_func partition start-time: 2022-01-12 02:41:13.639800 : Hello
```

Now, here I can see, all 5 rows started in 10 seconds interval which  I mentioned in function "**my_func**".

Can we start each partition at same time in PySpark ?
Within the partition, each row can have intervals of 10 secs. In this case, output should look like below to start 1st row of each Partition in same time seconds:

```
my_func partition start-time: 2022-01-12 02:40:33.617131 : World
my_func partition start-time: 2022-01-12 02:40:43.617869 : World
my_func partition start-time: 2022-01-12 02:40:33.637929 : Hello
my_func partition start-time: 2022-01-12 02:41:43.638729 : Hello
my_func partition start-time: 2022-01-12 02:41:03.639800 : Hello
```

[best required case, if we can start all rows at same time].

Comment: Perhaps you can try `df.repartition(5)` instead of `df.repartition('COL1')`.

Comment: @mazaneicha, just curious, will that help to start process in parallel ?
If so, then why 1st entry of 'Hello' and 'World' didn't executed in same time ? Any idea ?
And, also let's assume partition by column 'col1' also creates partitions having almost equal number of rows.

Comment: another reason I can think of is if your `spark.master` is set to `local`, or you have a single executor with 1 core. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls

Comment: How can I make sure that my below code writes all files parallel?

logFolderFQDN=f"dbfs:/mnt/ticstorageaccoun/build/{PARM_DATABASE_NAME}/"

df_partition=df_filter.repartition(totalPartitions,"partition_key")
print(f'data is partitioned! {totalPartitions}')

df_partition.write.mode("overwrite").options(header='true', inferschema='true', delimiter='|', quote="\"", escape="\"", nullValue="""""",).format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save(logFolderFQDN)
print('data processing is completed!')